# Как установить Android 11 на VirtualBox/VMware?

Tags: android, virtualbox, vmware

Когда я устанавливаю на VirtualBox или VMware Android 11 (Bliss OS 14.10) система не запускается и зависает на  этом экране загрузки, и как её надо устанавливать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не уверен, что голый VirtualBox способен запустить андроид, но я для андроида использую Genymotion. Вроде как работает на VirtualBox

Comment: Вот тут человек все подробно обьясняет https://youtu.be/Efvux7d0zD0?si=cmJTYIjL3Lthv5nq